# Need help in python lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm a new person to coding and while creating this program i had a thought

Q- make a program where you can see the amount of money the people who have deposited money in the bank will get after 1 year with 12% intrest on it and calculate the total intrest paid in 1 year

Ans-

```
balance= [12000,10000,33000,55000]

total= 0

for i in balance :

    intst= i*12*1/100

    total= total + intst

    print("intres of",i,"=",intst)

print("total intrest paid by the bank in 1 year =",total)
```

I wondered if i could specify names of the people who had deposited the money in it and when it prints it would show up like xxxx deposited `12000 = 1440.0`

I'm sorry if this sounds too complicated or stupid I'm just genuinely curious to see if it's possible

I tried using dictionary but horribly failed lmao

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Please carefully think about the code, then think of a specific **question** and **ask** it. Do not talk about yourself. Instead, directly explain: 1) what do you want the code to do? 2) What is the code? 3) What happens when you try that code? 4) How is that different from what you want? 5) **What is your question** about this difference?

Comment: We can't design program features for you. Make sure you know **exactly what** you want the code to do, before writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary can be used in the format {"Name" : 1000} # 1000 being the deposit amount

```py
interest_rate = 0.12
balances = {
    "John": 12000,
    "Joseph": 10000,
    "Joline": 33000,
    "Jose": 55000
}
interests = []
for name in balances:
    deposit = balances[name]
    interest = deposit * interest_rate
    print(f"{name} deposited {deposit}, after one year, the interest was {interest}")
```

Output:

```
John deposited 12000, after one year, the interest was 1440.0
Joseph deposited 10000, after one year, the interest was 1200.0
Joline deposited 33000, after one year, the interest was 3960.0
Jose deposited 55000, after one year, the interest was 6600.0
```